# Retrieve announcements from steam group

Tags: steam

I'm wondering if it is possible to get a list of announcements from a steam group if I have the groupID. I've been able to get events and members as an xml file, however I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to retrive the announcements.

Comment: How about RSS, a la https://github.com/nathan-hoad/steamnews?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isn't that for news on games?